# How Do I Set Margins To Meet KDP Requirements?

Tags: pdftex, books, linux, publishing

I'm new to LaTeX (started yesterday). I was looking for a way to automate/dramatically speed up interior layout for print books with consistent design across the entire PDF, using a few templates that I plan to set up over the next week or so, and LaTeX seemed like a simpler solution than InDesign. I'm not sure if LaTeX is really fit for that purpose, but I'm trying it out and it seems good so far - getting it to do everything I want is going to take some learning, of course.

I want to set my margins to meet the KDP paperback interior guidelines detailed here for a 6x9in 130-page interior PDF with no bleed: https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G201857950

I'm not *really* sure what I'm doing, or how to do it in LaTeX, but this is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, inner=0.375in, outer=0.5in, bindingoffset=0.375in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

I got these values from doing a lot of searching around, and just setting values in increments of 0.125 until it "looked right". Judging from the KDP guidelines page, I first tried to set it as:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, bindingoffset=0.375in, outer=0.25in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

But this seems wrong. It would seem to me that the text is far too close to the edge of the PDF on the outer side, and looking at other 6x9in print PDFs, the outer margin is indeed a lot larger.

I believe the `book` documentclass is setup to automatically enable mirror margins with `twoside`, which seems to be working correctly.

I've also read that `bindingoffset`is what sets up mirror margins, or perhaps I'm misinterpreting what I've read. I've interpreted that as KDP's "inside (gutter) margins".

I set `top` and `bottom` to 1in, as this seems to be the standard for most interiors of this trim size.

While I have stumbled across the KDP document class on github (https://github.com/JenniferMack/latex-kdp), I don't believe that it sets margins, and even if it does, I would rather learn how to set margins correctly myself, so I can change them to suit the printer's guidelines.

KDP doesn't advise anything in regard to `inner` margins from this page, but on this much more detailed page, they have a video setting the `inner` and `outer` margins to 0.375in, so I just went with that.

I think that my current setup is fine, and is probably within KDP's bounds for printing, but I want to know how to do it correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `right` and `outer` mean the same thing, as do `left` and `inner`. If you specify it twice in the options list, only one of them will take effect. Unless you are using the `asymmetric` option to get the even and odd side pages have margins that are _not_ mirror images of each other, you can just add the `bindingoffset` into your `inner` and not specify it separately.

Comment: If you want one-inch margins from the outside edge of the paper, and one-inch margin in the inside from where the binding happens, then you can just specify `[inner=1.375in, outer=1in]` and be done with it. (Figure 6 in on page 10 of the documentation for `geometry` package can be useful.)

Comment: the `geometry` package has also some pretty sensible defaults. For example, it may be easier for you to specify `bindingoffset=0.375in` and `width` and `height` of the text body, and let the package figure out the inner/outer/top/bottom margins.

Comment: Note that the github page says: "While not difficult, having the page size defined in the options to a package like `geometry` introduces the chance of an error creeping in. This class solves that problem by providing presets that take the guesswork out of setting up the page size." There are 14 page-size options: "Simply add the desired page size to the class options as you would with any other paper size. The 6x9 size is the default, other sizes are chosen like so:

    `\documentclass{kdp} % 6"x9"

    \documentclass[500paper]{kdp} % 5"x8"`"

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, I mistyped  `top`/`bottom` as`left`/`right`, but it's been fixed now. You also make a very good point about combining `inner` and `bindingoffset` together, and your solution would satisfy my requirements. However, because I want more control over the layout, I'll be moving to the `memoir` class.

Comment: @Cicada While I am no expert in LaTeX, I did skim the code on that github page, and it didn't seem to define any margins. I was under the impression that it only dealt with the trim size, which seems to be corroborated by the snippet of the `readme` you've posted here. I could be wrong, however.

Answer (score 4):

KDP specifies the safe minimum margins, not the actual margins of the pages that you will use in a book.  It is a  “no trespass” zone. Let's put this topic aside for the moment.

The first task when designing a book page is to decide the size and location of the text area on the physical page. (Actually, you will first have to choose the main font of the book.)

To be clearer, I will refer to the edge margin and spine margin instead of the right or left margin because in books the outer margin is on the right side on even pages and on the left side on odd pages.

*Note on design parameters*. This is not an exact science since it is based on ancient conventions, aesthetic opinions and same ergonomics related to the size of physical books, the way we read, the binding used, etc. You will find many options and firm opinions which reflect the author preferences, like I will do next. Most of the prescriptions and rules also have exceptions.
Feel free to disagree.

After choosing the main font family and font size for your book, you will continue with:

*1. Text area size.*

To maintain the reading flow, the lines should not be too long nor too short. For one column text, it is most often accepted that a 60-70 characters line wide is the best option. The exact width will depend on the font family and its size. Assuming a font size of 10 pt for the popular serif families for books, you will get a number of around 300 pt for the width. (1in=72.27pt). This is just to get started.

If you are a purist, you could set it to an exact width of 65 characters, once you settle on the main font you will use. Unless it exceeds 75 or is less than 55 characters, the reader will not notice any difference.

The height is often chosen as 1.6 times the width, because of the golden ratio, and because it gives a nice proportion to the eye and the Greeks had great taste on that point. And also because the form factor of commercial paper is rectangular in shape, so this choice is the most natural way to go. So set the text height to 480 pt. Some people will use the golden ratio to 4 or 5 decimal places. Nonsense, as you will see.

*2. Position of the text area on the page.*

This is a point of debate. Think of a book that is read in an open state, with both odd and even pages in view.
Each even page should be a mirror of the odd page, but how? Some people will recommend using positions for the two text areas that equally distribute the 3 blank areas.

This means that the total space of the blank area in the center, between the two printed areas, is equal to the margin of the edges. As a consequence, it will be recommended to set the spine margin to half the width of the edge margin.

I found this nice when two individual pages sit side by side on the design desk, but very inappropriate for a paperback book, or even on more expensive hardback books, because first, the binding consumes paper space and second, more importantly, because of the curvature of the pages when opening a book.

You can  handle the binding issue by specifying a binding of 20 points or more in your configuration, depending on the number of pages. This will reserve the necessary paper space for binding. (Measure the width of the binding with a book from your library.)

The second effect, the curl of the pages is less noticeable in a more expensive hardcover book where the inside pages are joined in smaller sections and then all them glued to the spine, but the effect still exists.

After some calculations and experiments, I was satisfied with a spine margin roughly equal to the edge margin. That gave me, in a bound book, an “optical distance” between the odd and even area (equal to two spine margins) similar to the edge margin (as prescribed by the above mentioned aesthetic canon) and wide enough to avoid the need to turn the book slightly to the right or to the left while reading, to see the text that landed too close to the spine margin.

For book publishing, I (strongly) recommend the class `memoir` because it gives you everything you need for the work and also integrates many other useful packages, saving a lot of trouble with updates.

The manual is excellent, it explains everything in detail and has many examples and templates to choose from, including chapter titles, table of contents, title pages, etc.

The class book is good, but `memoir` is better and well maintained.

Once you make you choices for the layout of the page, `memoir` will check the compatibility of the parameters and, if needed, slightly adjust the height of the text area to fit a whole number of lines in the text area. Very important for the facing pages of a book! There goes your 4 digits golden ratio.

In the MWE example, I will show the choices I usually make for a 6x9in paperback for KDP. Note that `geometry` it is not needed. Also important is the fact that the important dimensions are not absolute values but are related to the font, so they will be adjusted automatically if you later choose to change the family or size.

For better readability, I prefer a larger line spacing than the baseline defaults. Sometimes 15-25% larger and capable of collecting around 30 lines per page.

Now we can return to your question.

The red lines in the first image show the KDP “do not pass” safety margins. I published books over 250 pages long, so I use .5in and .3in for the inner and outer KDP margins. The green zone and lines mark the area defined by `memoir` configuration: text space and headers. The blue zone is your safe area, to use with page numbers, margin notes, logos, or decoration. As can be seen, you will be a long way from KDP's safe area, unless you plan to live dangerously, for example allowing a large table to go beyond the reserved margin area and ignoring LaTeX complaints.

[image: kdp]

In conclusion the KDP security area is quite far from the text area, the
header area, and the margin reserved area, so you still have enough room to reposition all items or increase the binding space if you want. On a properly designed page, KDP margins are not a cause for concern. KDP claims that many manuscripts are rejected for violating these rules, but that should never happen to a LaTeX (`memoir`) user.

After the compilation `memoir` will report

```
Stock height and width: 650.43pt by 433.62pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 650.43pt by 433.62pt
Text height and width: 460pt by 282pt
Spine and edge margins: 85.74673pt and 65.74673pt
Upper and lower margins: 90pt and 100.43pt
Headheight and headsep: 30pt and 30pt
```

Notice that the spine margin is equal to the edge margin plus 20pt (the binding space reserved, that will be consumed when the pages are glued together).

You can view graphically the complete configuration using the `layout` package.

The second image shows what two facing pages will look like in an open book, after running the following code.

```
 % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt, a5paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{layout} %shows the layout of the page

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype} % a must

%% ***************** page design

\linespread{1.250000}  %expand baseline to 15pt
\setstocksize{9in}{6in} % 6 x 9 in
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}

\setlxvchars %define lenght 65 char of the used font
\settypeblocksize{*}{1.0\lxvchars}{1.6}  % almost the golden ratio
\setbinding{20pt}  % allow for binding space
\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}

\setulmargins{90pt}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*} % might be used to horizontal displacements
\setheaderspaces{*}{30pt}{*} % Sets the spacing above and below the header

\setmarginnotes{0.01pt}{20pt}{\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout %important!!
%%********************** end page design

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
    
\layout  %be sure to check the layout!

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

\chapter{First chapter of the Book}

Footnote.\footnote{A first page footnote }
\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: face2face]

Visual appearance of an open bound paperback book.

[image: open]

Comment: This is a fantastic response! You've gone above and beyond what I asked, and I'm incredibly grateful for it, and I'm sure it will be very useful for whoever else is struggling with margin requirements. While I don't understand everything, the `memoir` class's documentation should clear that up. I have two questions: when specifying the `documentclass`, does it matter what papersize you choose if you are setting the `stocksize` and `trimsize` later? It doesn't seem to, which is ideal. Secondly, for handling nonfree fonts, would you recommend XeLaTeX, or is LaTeX fine? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Not really necessary. `memoir` will honor the settings you wrote in the preamble.
 I kept it in the invocation of the class just for testing. If you have `\checkandfixthelayout` in place,  `memoir` will write the full layout to your console and to the log file, which is a nice feature to document the result while testing slightly different layouts. Try it yourself.
 
 The KDP paper size is different from ANSI or ISO 216 standards, so you must specify 6x9 inches explicitly.

Comment: More important is the `twoside` option. For a digital document, which will not be printed on facing pages, `memoir` doesn't mind having every last line lined up on facing pages, so you will get far fewer `vbox undefull` warnings.
 
 2. To easily use any font you want, you should use `fontspec` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex. You can specify a font that is already in your system directory, for example `c:\Windows\Fonts`, or in your project directory (be careful of TeX naming requirements for directory trees) without additional packages.

Answer (score 1):

The KDP guidelines specify very little about the page layout, so most of it is up to you. You might like to consider using the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report` with many additional facilities). Here is a possible layout design for you.

```
% KDPprob.tex  SE 569994

%\documentclass[smallroyalvopaper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}  % stocksize 9.25 by 6.175 in
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}  % stocksize A4
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*} % final page size after trimming
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*} % upper and lower margins defining typeblock height
% according to KDP width of typeblock no more than 5.375in 
% about 65 characters per line is good for reading. For many 12pt fonts
% this gives a line length of about 2.5 alphabet lengths as about 5.2in.
% For 10pt fonts the line length is about 4.5in. Lets say the line length
% is to be 5in which calls for a 0.625in outer margin.
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.375in}{0.625in}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The class provides many means of defining the document's layout, some of which I used above.

Essentially you have to create a good layout for your readers within the confines of your publisher's restrictions. Chapter **Two** *Laying out the page* in the `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`) discusses this in some depth, describing the commands to create your own page layout and showing  example page layouts used over the centuries.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the `memoir` class seems like it is much more fit for this purpose than the standard `book` or `report` classes, so I will be switching to it. Thank you also for pointing to a specific area of the documentation for me to learn more about laying out pages, as I am new to it. The MWE you provided is great, too; it's simple enough that I understand everything that's going on without even having to read the documentation (although I will regardless) and satisfies my requirements.