# More explanation about page layout when printing a book

Tags: book-design, printing

I read in the memoir class manual, in chapter 2, about some additional lengths that you should set up when preparing documents for printing. For example, the length for the spine, the difference between typeblock and paper size, and the difference between paper height and stock height.

I got a bit confused with all those lengths, and therefore I am looking for a text that describes better the preparation of a book sent to print.

Any suggestion for such a resource?

This is a not a question about TeX, so maybe you can direct me to a more appropriate site where I can get an answer.

Comment: If you are using a publisher: that's their job, not yours. If you are self publishing using something like Lulu or Amazon, they should have FAQ on exactly what information they need. For example, my local university library has a book printing service, and provides https://lib.msu.edu/publish/selfpublish/

Comment: Basically: books are often printed on paper that are larger than the final product size, and then trimmed (this helps if you want printed material to go all the way to the edge of the printed page, for example). Binding will take up physical space too. So when you are designing a book to be printed and bound, you need to allocate those extra room.

Comment: Thanks. So how is this "extra room" size called, in the printers jargon? Reading the "Calculating Spine Size" paragraph in the link you shared, I understand that this size is calculated only after finishing writing the book. What is the effect of choosing a smaller or larger spine size than the suggested one? These are the things I would like the understand better.

Comment: I wrote a long answer some time ago. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570082/161015

Comment: @SimonDispa Thanks a lot! I should read it carefully.

Comment: Perhaps my *A Few Notes on Book Design* --- `texdoc memdesign`.